# Match .extension, except .word.extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried:

`.[^(word)]\.extension$`

(Which 'word' is a **particular** word)

Comment: use a lookbehind! https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html

Comment: language, you are using?

Comment: **[this](https://regex101.com/r/yQ7cA5/1)**

Comment: Try [`^(?:(?![.]word).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/aL0vZ7/1)

Comment: look be hind isnt supported by javascript

Comment: Then, you can try [`(?:[.](?!word)\S+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/aL0vZ7/3)

Answer (score 1):

Since JS.

If it's a small line of text, use BOL anchor and a lookahead.

`^(?!.*\.word\.extension$).*\.extension$`